# Making tinyscrollbar work with changing, animating content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinyscrollbar

[I'm using tinyscrollbar](http://jsfiddle.net/J74VS/7/) to show a nice scrollbar.

Part of my content is hidden (`display:none`), and only shown after a button is clicked, in a `slideDown()`/`slideToggle()` animation.

When I reveal the extra content, the scrollbar does not update, and part of the content is now unreachable. Is there a solution that updates smoothly with the animation?

FYI, here is a non-smooth solution (just call `.tinyscrollbar()` again after the animation finishes):

```
$(".toggler").slideToggle().promise().then(function(){
  $("#scrollbar").tinyscrollbar()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the the tinyscrollbar_update() method. Thats a lot cleaner then initializing the scrollbar again.

```
$(".toggler").slideToggle().promise().then(function(){
  $('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar_update();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I found that out by now ... thanks. Although it's still not smooth, perhaps this should be a comment instead.

Comment: If you want a smoother animation. Its probably better to make the animation yourself with a setTimeout. Then you can control the whole animation and call the update method on certain points during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use 'relative'

```
$('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar_update();
```

There will be no need to animate scrollbar after toggle content. This solution has helped in my issue.